# Eclipse Indigo: eclipse executable unable to locate its companion shared library

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I am trying to launch eclipse from my ubuntu command line as follows,

```
/opt/test/eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse -showsplash 600 -product org.myproduct -data /opt/test/workspace/../tester_runtime -configuration file:/opt/test/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/tester_runtime/ -dev file:/opt/test/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/tester_runtime/dev.properties -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -nl en_US -consoleLog --disableLoginDialog
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
eclipse executable unable to locate its companion shared library
/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My eclipse is in `/opt/test` but in the error it's trying to find it in `/opt`.
What is happening here? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Unless your Ubuntu version is also from 2011, why not try the latest Luna release?